# how to add subsmenu with this css

Tags: html, css, menubar

I want to make a submenu on this vertical menu bar. I know that I must to change the css in order to make submenu but I'm not well using css3.The css file that i'm using not provide for submenu code. The real html code is like this

```
      <body><ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="pagehome.php">
                    <span class="ca-icon">D</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Home</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="settingpage.php">
                    <span class="ca-icon">S</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Setting</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul></body>
```

I want to add two more vertical submenu when user hover to this menu(Setting)..Like this

```
    <body><ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="pagehome.php">
                    <span class="ca-icon">D</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Home</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'>
                <a href="settingpage.php">
                    <span class="ca-icon">S</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Setting</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
                       <!-- this UL will be openning for new submenu
                       <ul>  
                            <li><a href="settingpage.php">         <!-- Edit Here
                                 <span class="ca-icon">S</span>    <!-- Edit Here
                                 <div class="ca-content">          <!-- Edit Here
                                 <h2 class="ca-main">Submenu 1</h2><!-- Edit Here
                                 </div></a>
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="settingpage.php">        <!-- Edit Here
                                 <span class="ca-icon">S</span>    <!-- Edit Here
                                 <div class="ca-content">          <!-- Edit Here
                                 <h2 class="ca-main">Submenu 2</h2><!-- Edit Here
                                 </div></a>
                            </li>
                       </ul>
                       this UL will be end for new submenu -->
            </li>
        </ul></body>
```

This is the CSS3 file that I'm using

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
 src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
 src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
.ca-menu{
 padding:0;
 margin:5px auto;
 width: 145px;
}
.ca-menu li{
 width: auto;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child{
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a{
 text-align: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 color: #333;
 position: relative;
}

.ca-icon{
 font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #333;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 9px;
 left: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.ca-content{
 position: absolute;
 left: 30px;
 width: 370px;
 height: 60px;
 top: 5px;
}
.ca-main{
 line-height: 25px;
 font-size: 15px;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.ca-sub{
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #666;
}
.ca-menu li:hover{
 background-color: #000;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
 color: #f900b0;
 font-size: 120px;
 opacity: 0.2;
 left: -20px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
 transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
 color: #f900b0;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ It would help a lot if we could execute this stuff.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v8k7k/1/  this the example what I'm doing.
the arrow is where I want the submenu will be and The font that zoom is actually icon like this demo http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/index3.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your stylesheet:

```css
.ca-menu .has-sub > ul { display: none; }
.ca-menu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    top: -100%;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0;
}
.ca-menu li { overflow: visible; }
.ca-menu a { overflow: hidden; }
```

and modify the following...
...on line 84 from:

```
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
```

to:

```
.ca-menu li:hover > a > .ca-icon{
```

...on line 94 from:

```
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
```

to:

```
.ca-menu li:hover > a > .ca-content > .ca-main{
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SKhh/1/)

Here you find a nice summary on CSS selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: wah it work miss Maria....thank you..
but miss maria how can the submenu be the same like the menu setting animation..I mean the submenu also will have the same animation parent menu

Comment: anyone please help.........just need to make the animation of submenu same with parent menu.......

Comment: I have edited my answer above. I hope now it works for you as you expected.

Comment: Maria thank for your help....you make my day...
I don't how to thank you more..I'm cannot vote bcoz my reputation is not enough..by the way very2 big thank...